# SQL Counting of Different Values

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to figure out how to put the count of a field when it equals different conditions.

For instance I have a

```
SELECT DISTINCT FileName, ReasonCode
from TBL1
```

where
I want to be able to select a distinct file name and show the count of ReasonCode = x (name this column count of x), ReasonCode = y (name this column count of y), ReasonCode = z (count of z).

I want to output all of this one 1 row for that distinct file name.

So that it has a FileName field, count of x field, count of y field, and count of z field

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT FileName,
       sum(case when ReasonCode = 'x' then 1 else 0 end) as x_count,
       sum(case when ReasonCode = 'y' then 1 else 0 end) as y_count,
       sum(case when ReasonCode = 'z' then 1 else 0 end) as z_count
from TBL1
group by FileName
```

Comment: Some times the same file name will have a few instances with the ReasonCode equal to x and a few with it equal to y, I need it to show the count for all of them in 1 line.

Comment: That is what this query does. Why did you not test it?

Comment: I did, it will give me file name, 0 for x, 2 for y, 0 for z then it will give me the same file name, 2 for x, 0 for y, 0 for z

Comment: Then the filename is slightly different. Maybe some spaces in one of them.